# Is it possible to config multiple routes with ODATA

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I've created a project containing both MVC and WebAPI.

There's a MVC controller named HomeController which containing only one action named Index. 
Also, there's a API controller named ValuesController.

Everything works fine without OData, I can access to both http://localhost/Home/Index and http://localhost/api/Values successfully.

However, after I changed some code to support OData, I'm failed to access to http://localhost/Home/Index. Below is the related code:

```java
//startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddDbContext<ProductsContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDb");
    });

    //Adding OData middleware.
    services.AddOData();
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider provider){
    if (env.IsDevelopment()){
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    //Adding Model class to OData
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(provider);
    builder.EntitySet<ValuesEntity>("Values");

    builder.EntityType<ValuesEntity>().Filter(QueryOptionSetting.Allowed).OrderBy(QueryOptionSetting.Allowed);

    //Enabling OData routing.
    app.UseMvc(routebuilder =>
    {
        routebuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "api", builder.GetEdmModel());

        routebuilder.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

**As you can see, there're multiple routes, but the default route seems never get used.**

I can still access to the http://localhost/api/Values, but If I access to the http://localhost/Home/Index, the page will show me the error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: routeName
>   Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions.HttpRequestExtensions.CreateRequestScope(HttpRequest request, string routeName)